# AngularJS testing with RxJS 5 debounceTime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, rxjs

I Have a Component that renders an label and input 
And on the $postLink I add an Overver to my input focus, and if the focus event is triggered, I set an internal variable `focused` to `true`

```
$postLink() { 
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent(myInputElement, 'focus')
      .debounceTime(200)
      .subscribe(() => {
      this.focused = true;
      this.$scope.$evalAsync();
    });
}
```

In my test file (I'm using Jasmine), I have something like this:

```
it('must set "focused" to true when input get focused', () => {
  // The setupTemplate return a angular.element input, my component controller and scope
  const { input, controller, parentScope } = setupTemplate();
  input[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
  $timeout.flush(600);
  parentScope.$digest();
  expect(controller.focused).toBe(true);
});
```

But my test fails.

If I remove the `debounceTime` from my component method, the test pass.

What can I do to simulate the `debounceTime`?

Comment: The test is asynchronous so you can use `it('...', done => {})` and then call `done()` manually

Comment: @martin THAAANKS!!!, that's It =DD

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @martin, my test is green.

I've just added an **done** to the callback, and invoked in a **setTimeout**

```
it('must set "focused" to true when input get focused', (done) => {
  const { input, controller, parentScope } = setupTemplate();
  input[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(controller.focused).toBe(true);
    done();
  }, 300);
});
```